# Wind Force of a projectile

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

I am currently working on a program that models the projectile motion of a baseball with air resistance and wind acting upon it. However, I cannot find the equation to calculate the force of the wind, that I can use for my program.

As of now I have:
$$x(max)=[ [v_{0}^2*sin(2\theta)]/g]- [4v_{0}^3 sin(2\theta)sin(\theta)/3g^2]*\gamma$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics SE. Please, use laTex notation for formulae. It's about writing them in between of dollar symbols, and laTex commands inside. See here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: How have you obtained that formula? Have you tried easy models like Stoke's law?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)#Types_of_drag

Comment: FGSUZ, I used a model from an analytical mechanics book. The first part of the equation represents the model of the ball with no linear air resistance and the second is the deduction due to air resistance. I'm looking to add wind into the equation but can't quite figure out if it would be better to include in my air resistance or subtract it separately.